# Create Dynamics CRM Relationship Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I see how to do basic crud operations on CRM entities using Logic Apps.  Is there a way to create a relationship between two entities?  In a one -> one, one -> many and many -> many cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  What you're probably looking to use is the AssociateRequest message which is it's own Entity in the SDK.

You will likely have to work with the owners of CRM on specific details.