# Create/Retrieve CRM N:N Relationship using Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I would like to use the Logic Apps Dynamics CRM connector to retrieve records for a many-to-many relationship and also add a record to a many-to-many relationship.  The relationship entity is teammembership_association.

How can I do this using the CRM connector?

My question is similar to this one:
[Create Dynamics CRM Relationship Azure Logic App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753173/create-dynamics-crm-relationship-azure-logic-app), but some further detail would be great.

Comment: you should create the logic app, give it a try and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything preventing you from doing this.  Keep in mind, Relationships are just Entities.

To get all the Relationships, you may need to first List Records, then Get Records, but in the end, you will have all the Relationships.